# Stuck in a bad team. How to make the best of a worst situation?

Tags: software-industry, colleagues, career-development

I have been in a team for more than a year and I am stuck. The company works on proprietary software and I don't have much guidance. I waste all my time going round in circles and I can barely get other team members to give me some basic info. My weekend and weekdays are also lost because of this.

This is my first job out of college and I used to be a good programmer. The pay is decent but I want to change. I failed few interviews for lack of practice. I can't make time to practice Leetcode and above all, I am getting fed up with all the work that keeps getting piled up.

I believe I am trapped. I  can't do a team change within company for minimum another year. How to get out of this mess ?  (Any advice)

Should I resign and stay at home ? (Easier to get a job while you are still employed )

Comment: Have you talked to your manager to get some input or someone to help you ? Do they have any documentations ?  I understand the importance of making time to practice Leetcode. But, certainly, you are right that it's "easier to get a job while you are still employed". Once you quit a job, there is no way to know when you may get the next job offer.

Comment: It seems to me that, in your view,  everyone else is to blame for your problems.  This is virtually NEVER the case.  Take stock of your own skillset, career goals, and attitude and form a plan going forward.  Take responsibility for your own career and life!

Answer (score 4):

Never resign without having another job lined up. There are many other answers on this site that explain why. Don't do it.

Your question reads like you are burning out. I would focus on getting your mind back on track.

1. Practice detaching yourself from the stuff happening in your workplace: What happens at work, stays at work. Never think about work when you are not on the clock. Do some hobbies, meet with friends, focus on something different.
2. If you don't get enough training on the job, don't try to compensate by training yourself on the weekends. This will burn you out. If you want to practice your programming skills, do so. But don't train/work on the weekends "because your boss told you so".
3. Don't beat yourself up if you feel inadequate at work. You are a beginner. Beginners make mistakes.
4. Schedule a meeting with your supervisor. List stuff that's holding you back. Try not to whine, detach yourself emotionally. Only state what prevents you from working at your full potential. If your supervisor is non-commital, agree on a timeframe when you meet again and review if something has improved.
5. If your company is not what you are looking for, you should continue looking for new opportunities. Analyze what your weaknesses are in the interview process, and work on those. You can ask friends to "play" interview with you, or you can do whiteboard coding. Most interview problems arise from being nervous. Try to relax, don't try too hard.

Answer (score 0):

When you do have time to yourself take time to reflect and re-organize. Where you want to work, what you can do in terms of your skills and abilities, goals either at the same company or career goals in general and decide if your goals can be better met at the current company or with a different one. As for interviewing no problem. If you can practice interviewing with a friend or watching videos on interviewing tips. Now as for leetcode practicing you know your schedule better than any of us so maybe take a look at it and determine what activities you feel you could do without and practice then. Just remember there's always a solution.